# ObjectParameterError when saving to database with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a small blog until now everything works great but now that I try to add a second Schema for categories I got this error  `ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got` .
This is the part of the code that is been interested:

```js
const blog_create_post = (req, res) => {
    const blog = new Blog(req.body);
    const category = new Category(req.body.category)
    ...
}
```

The first declaration work, but the second one send me the error
Full error:

```js
ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got <text>
```

This is `req.body`:

```js
body: {
    category: 'wdawda',
    title: 'awdawd',
    snippet: 'dawdaw',
    body: 'dawdawda'
  }
```

Mongoose Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = new Schema({
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
module.exports = Category;
```

I tried this:

```js
var things = req.body.category
const category = new Category(things);
```

and I don't have any error until the next line. This is the whole function:

```js
const blog_create_post = (req, res) => {
    const blog = new Blog(req.body);
    var things = { category: req.body.category };
    const category = new Category(things);
    if (!Category.exists({ category: things })) {
        console.log('category not exist');
        category.save()
        .then((result) => {
            blog.save()
            .then((result) => {
                res.redirect('/blogs');
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        })
        .catch((err) => res.send(err));
    } else {
        console.log('category exist');
        blog.save()
            .then((result) => {
                res.redirect('/blogs');
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

the new error is this:

```js
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ category: 'awdawd' }" at path "category" for model "Category"
```

Comment: I'v got another error: 
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: same error as before, the only things that change is the position number: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: This is `req.body`: `{
  category: 'dawda',
  title: 'dawda',
  snippet: 'awdawd',
  body: 'awdawdawd'
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const category = new Category({ category: req.body.category })
```

This line in the blog_create_post function:

```
const blog_create_post = (req, res) => {
    const blog = new Blog(req.body);
    const category = new Category({ category: req.body.category });
    ...
}
```

I pass a object with "category" attribute instead of "category" value directly.